# Use shared_preferences to get theme at startup

Tags: flutter, dart-async

How do I set the theme of my app based on what's stored in `shared_preferences` if all calls to `shared_preferences` are async?

For example, I have a `ThemeService` which looks up the set theme from `shared_preferences` and returns it, this works for things like toggling it in the UI, but how do I load this at startup?

```
class ThemeService {

  static String key = "isDark";

  /// Return the ThemeData based on what is persisted.
  Future<ThemeData> getTheme() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    final isDarkMode = prefs.getBool(key) ?? false;

    if (isDarkMode) {
      return ThemeDark().theme;
    } else {
      return ThemeLight().theme;
    }
  }

  /// Toggle the theme between light/dark and persist the chosen value.
  Future<void> toggleTheme() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    final isDarkMode = prefs.getBool(key) ?? false;

    if (isDarkMode) {
      Get.changeTheme(ThemeLight().theme);
      await prefs.setBool(key, false);
    } else {
      Get.changeTheme(ThemeDark().theme);
      await prefs.setBool(key, true);
    }
  }
}
```

And I want to be able to use it as such:

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {

  final ThemeService themeService = Get.find<ThemeService>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        initialBinding: InitialBinding(),
        initialRoute: initialRoute(),
        theme: themeService.getTheme(), // Its a future, so can't do this...
        getPages: AppPages.routes);
  }
}
```

New to flutter so have I just missed a concept or a pattern here? Is there some way I should be accessing the preferences as to not need `async/await`?

Comment: Try to put a `FutureBuilder` around your `GetMaterialApp` https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the solution is to wrap the `GetMaterialApp` in a `FutureBuilder`

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<ThemeData>(
        future: ThemeService().getTheme(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<ThemeData> snapshot) {
          return GetMaterialApp(
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              initialBinding: InitialBinding(),
              initialRoute: initialRoute(),
              theme: snapshot.data,
              darkTheme: darkTheme,
              getPages: AppPages.routes);
        });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I will make the `main` async. So the code will be more less like:

```
void main() async {
  final themeService = ThemeService();
  final initialTheme = await themeService.getTheme();
  
  runApp(App(initialTheme: initialTheme));
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  
  final ThemeData initialTheme;

  const App({Key? key, this.initialTheme}) : super(key: key); 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        initialBinding: InitialBinding(),
        initialRoute: initialRoute(),
        theme: initialTheme, // <-- Now can do it
        getPages: AppPages.routes);
  }
}
```